# JPEGCodec dependency OpenJDK

Tags: java, api, migration, deprecated

I have a legacy jar that uses "com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.*" - this are removed in the OpenJDK8. At runtime i get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGImageEncoder.

Any "clean" solution to this ?

I have created a jar file with the required dependencies ( all the classes from com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.* ), i've added it to the classpath and it solves my issue.

There is no way I can de-compile the legacy jar and re-compile it with the correct code usage. ( using ImageIO ).

I'm using :

openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_222-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: No clean solutions exist.  Other than getting the *real* source code of legacy JAR and porting it.

Comment: Can you provide some instructions on how exactly you did that? I'm facing the exact same issue right now.